# When does the zero-fill operation take place for an array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, initialization

Consider this in C#:

```
int[] a = new int[1024];
```

All integers will be set to 0. Traditionally, this is done by a highly optimized zero-fill operation (e.g. `memset`). However, as this array is allocated by the CLR I can think of an optimization which is pretty straight-forward; the CLR could maintain a zeroed memory area to skip this zero-filling at the time we request our memory.

Now, does CLR perform such an optimization? (I'm currently using .NET 4.0)

Comment: Why would you care? Other than academic interest, of course.

Comment: I happen to have grown out from the world of C++, where programmers actually care about the underlying code. (And... dealing with huge memory blocks in CPU intensive algorithms, unnecessary zeroing may become a bottleneck. It makes sense to know when the zeroing occurs.)

Comment: '_Why would you care?'_ - Reminds me of [_'Why you readin' for?'_](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eZs9557NCAM)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This operates at a much lower level.  Windows keeps a low priority kernel thread alive whose only job is zero-ing the content of memory pages.  Called the "zero page thread".  Those pages are kept in a pool, ready for use to any process that generates a page fault for reserved but not committed pages.   *Any* code in Windows benefits from this, not just managed code.  The intention is security, not zero-ing the RAM content of mapped memory pages would allow a program to spy on the memory of another process.

This won't happen with your array, it is too small.  It gets allocated in the gen #0 heap, a heap that will always have mapped pages.  Large arrays however get allocated in the Large Object Heap, large is 85,000 bytes, 8000 bytes for an array of double.  LOH allocations *can* take advantage of getting the pages pre-initialized to zero.  Whether it actually does is hard to tell, the source code for that isn't available anywhere.  I'd say it is likely considering the amount of cpu cycles it saves.

Answer (score 2):

The CLR does only allocate a [bit more memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973837.aspx) than the managed heap consumes and then if it runs out of unallocated memory for the managed heap it will request more memory from the operation system. Prezeroing the memory would only take advantage if your process workingset it already big and you have a lot of unused memory that got garbage collected. This memory then is free for allocation from the managed heap.
If this is the case for your application you should think of reusing the array rather than dropping it to avoid the reallocation on the managed heap.

Comment: No, it won't call the constructor for a struct.  Structs do not have parameterless instance contructors (11.3.8 from the specification).  Structs are initialized by setting all value type fields to their default value.  Furthermore, elements of arrays created with a creation expression (vice an initializer) are always initialized to their default value.

Comment: @MikeCowan you are right, I mixed it with ctor's that contain a construct to and the enforcement of the compiler to initialize all the fields manually. Removed that part from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the IL produced for this code?  A call to `newarr` is likely generated for the call in question.  Per ECMA-355, `newarr` creates a new zero-based, one-dimensional array and initializes elements of the array to 0 of the appropriate type.  In this case, since it's an array of `int` the elements will be initialized to 0 at creation.